# Почему я не могу пользоваться подклассом шаблонного класса, передаваемого в функцию с шаблонным шаблоном?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl, контейнеры, auto

Я создал функцию `printVector`, выводящую содержимое любого вектора *(если для них определён оператор << соответственно)*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class templateType>
void printVector(vector<templateType>& container)
{
    for(vector<templateType>::iterator it = container.begin(); it != container.end() ; it++)
    {
        cout << *it<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> container = { 1,2,3 };
    printVector(container);
}
```

При определении шаблонного вектора в `printVector` я не могу создать объект его подкласса `iterator`:

```
vector<templateType>::iterator it; // ERROR
```

Данную проблему я решил, использовав `auto`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class templateType>
void printVector(vector<templateType>& container)
{
    for(auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end() ; it++)
    {
        cout << *it<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> container = { 1,2,3 };
    printVector(container);
}
```

Но всё - же интересно, почему я не могу создать объект подкласса с помощью его имени (`vector<templateType>::iterator`), но при этом могу с помощью `auto`?

Comment: Потому что в записи `vector<templateType>::iterator` до инстанцирования шаблона `iterator` не является именем типа без явного указания этого посредством `typename`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что в

```
for(vector<templateType>::iterator it = container.begin(); 
    it != container.end() ; it++)
{
```

компилятор не знает, что `iterator` - это тип. Может, это статическая переменная?

Чтобы пояснить ему, что это тип, надо написать

```
for(typename vector<templateType>::iterator it = container.begin(); 
    it != container.end() ; it++)
{
```